# Strange output when executing shell command with FAKE

Tags: .net, build, f#, f#-fake

My FAKE build script includes the following helper function:

```
let Exec command args =
    printfn "Command: %s %s" command args
    let result = Shell.Exec(command, args)
    printfn "After"
    if result <> 0 then failwithf "%s exited with error %d" command result
```

When I try to execute a zip command with this, I see the following:

[image]

I can't figure out why the asian characters are being output. The zip is created correctly. Running the zip command on its own in the terminal outputs only expected characters (all in English).

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Could it be that you're specifying `stdout` as `zip`'s output?

Comment: I don't specify stdout anywhere and even tried to `|> ignore` the execution result, but it didn't help. Also, the zip is created correctly, so it's not like the output is being redirected _only_ to stdout.

Comment: What OS is this running on?  How are you calling the function?

Comment: It's a FAKE bug with terminal color, or at least that's how I can repro.  If I rerun after seeing a bunch of Chinese (?) characters, I get good output.  The world would be a better place if command-line tools never, never, never used color.  Ever.  (I'm running on OSX)  Nothing to do with zip itself; try just creating a shell script that echos to stderr and you'll see the problem.